# Spring security 3.1.4 multiple http elements with form-login's

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am fully aware this question has been asked many times, but I have yet to stumble across the answer. If it is out there, I apologise and a link to it would be highly appreciated.

#### Current, working configuration

Below is a snippet of my currently working configuration, which allows access to the above block of `<http />` elements without any security, but requires an authenticated user with one of the roles to login.

```
<http pattern="/" security="none" disable-url-rewriting="true" />
<http pattern="/login" security="none" disable-url-rewriting="true" />
<http pattern="/cookieInfo" security="none" disable-url-rewriting="true" />
<http pattern="/error" security="none" disable-url-rewriting="true" />
<http pattern="/cookiesDisabled" security="none" disable-url-rewriting="true" />
<http pattern="/loginFailed" security="none" disable-url-rewriting="true" />
<http pattern="/static/**" security="none" disable-url-rewriting="true" />

<http access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" disable-url-rewriting="true">
    <custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="cookiePresentFilter" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_1,ROLE_2,ROLE_3" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url='/loginSuccess' always-use-default-target='true' authentication-failure-url="/loginFailed" />
    <logout />
</http>
```

#### Desired, not working configuration

I'd like to have a special section, shown below as `<http pattern="/foo/**" ...` which does not have a default target that is forced to be used. I was hoping that just having a more specific pattern before the catch all would be enough, however it seems to just use the final catch all block in all cases. I have tried with the `intercept-url pattern="/**"` being `intercept-url pattern="/foo/**"` also to no avail.

Any ideas?!

```
<http pattern="/" security="none" disable-url-rewriting="true" />
<http pattern="/login" security="none" disable-url-rewriting="true" />
<http pattern="/loginFailed" security="none" disable-url-rewriting="true" />
<http pattern="/static/**" security="none" disable-url-rewriting="true" />

<http pattern="/foo/**" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" disable-url-rewriting="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_1,ROLE_2,ROLE_3" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/loginFailed" />
    <logout />
</http>

<http access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" disable-url-rewriting="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_1,ROLE_2,ROLE_3" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url='/loginSuccess' always-use-default-target='true' authentication-failure-url="/loginFailed" />
    <logout />
</http>
```

Comment: To clarify... you want url of the pattern "/foo/**" to simply be public and unprotected by spring security?

Comment: Hi, sorry if it was unclear, but no, I wish it to be authenticated in the same way, just not be passed to the default target, and I was trying to see if this was possible via configuration rather than by having to do it in java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Why this doesn't work

The reason this does not work is because the following is happening:

- If you request a URL that matches /foo/** the page is cached in the [RequestCache](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/savedrequest/RequestCache.html). The default implementation is implemented by caching the request in HttpSession.
- Spring Security will then send you to /login which likely has a form on it that posts to /j_spring_security_check
- When a user authenticates the request is /j_spring_security_check and it does not match /foo/** so it is authenticated by the second  element. The `always-use-default-target="true"` is applied at time of authentication, not the time of sending to the login form. Since the request to authenticate does not match /foo/** the user will always be sent to the `default-target-url`

## Fixing this setup

To fix this, you would need to do the following:

```
<http pattern="/foo/**" ...>
    <intercept-url pattern="/foo/login" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_1,ROLE_2,ROLE_3" />
    <form-login
        ... 
        default-target-url="/loginSuccess 
        login-page="/foo/login" 
        login-processing-url="/foo/authenticate" />
    ...
</http>
```

**/foo/login**

```
<form method="post" action="<c:url value='/foo/authenticate'/>">
   ...
</form>
```

Highlights of the changes:

- Update the  block configuration to send to a different login page. This allows submitting to a custom URL that matches /foo/**
- Ensure that custom login page is granted access to anonymous users
- Update the  block configuration to process authentication on a URL that matches /foo/** This ensures that `always-use-default-target="false"`

## A better alternative

Spring Security will send users to the default-target-url if the RequestCache is empty. This means that if the RequestCache ignores requests that you want to send to the default-target-url everything will work.

For your example, you can do something like this:

```
<http access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" disable-url-rewriting="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_1,ROLE_2,ROLE_3" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url='/loginSuccess' always-use-default-target='true' authentication-failure-url="/loginFailed" />
    <logout />

    <request-cache ref="requestCache"/>
</http>

<bean:bean id="requestCache" class="org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache">
    <bean:property name="requestMatcher">
        <bean:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.util.RegexRequestMatcher">
            <bean:constructor-arg value="^(?!/foo/).+"/>
            <bean:constructor-arg><bean:null/></bean:constructor-arg>
            <bean:constructor-arg value="true"/>
        </bean:bean>
    </bean:property>
</bean:bean>
```

Highlights:

- Use the main  only (do not use the /foo/** block)
- Update the block to use [request-cache](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-request-cache) element
- Create an instance of HttpSessionRequestCache that only saves requests that should be redirected to. In other words, ignore requests that should always send to the default-target-url. The example configuration will send any request that does not match /foo/** to the default-target-url.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer. It is now quite obvious to me why what I was attempting wouldn't work, so thank you for setting me straight! With regard to the better alternative - I have given it a go, but it does not appear to have worked as it still goes to the default target when accessing a url beginning with /foo. I shall debug it over the weekend and see if I have done something wrong.

Comment: For my example /foo would be cached since it does not start with /foo/ Note the second / in the pattern

Comment: Sorry, I had tried urls that began /foo/... to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Change your config file to the following:

```
<http access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" disable-url-rewriting="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/foo/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_1,ROLE_2,ROLE_3" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url='/loginSuccess' always-use-default-target='true' authentication-failure-url="/loginFailed" />
    <logout />
</http>
```